# I logged in for the first time in a year and my level 3 skiller somehow became level 4

Tags: runescape

I logged in for the first time in a year and my level 3 skiller somehow became level 4. I had this skilled for like 4 years with some 99s and now I came back to check out what's going and its combat level is 4! It's totally ruined. I don't get it why and how. Was there some update related to this? My combat skills are all 1.

No, account wasn't hacked. When logged in it showed my IP from the last login and over 300 hundred days.

Also when logged in I appeared in the now ex-p2p zone above Falador to North-West in some new town.

So what the hell, why its level 4 suddenly if it was inactive for a year with combat skills all 1. Was there some kind of an update?

Comment: I disagree with the 'too localized' close vote on this.  Any answer would just needs to go through any possible reason your level could have gone up while inactive, and it looks like it does indeed have a definitive reason behind it.

Answer (score 5):

A little while ago, Jagex released an update called the [Evolution of Combat](http://services.runescape.com/m=news/the-evolution-of-combat). This update changed the entire combat system, including how combat levels are calculated. Your level 4 skiller with all level 1 combat stats now is the same as your level 3 skiller was before EoC.

Comment: Does that mean that level 4 is the new lowest level, even when creating a new account?

Comment: I think so. Just remember that combat level is calculated entirely from combat skill levels, so if all of your combat skills are at level 1, then you must be at the minimum combat level.

Answer (score 1):

Just elaborating on @murgatroid99's answer, the combat level formula changed with the release of the [Evolution of Combat](https://runescape.wiki/w/Evolution_of_Combat) on 20 November 2012.

Currently, the combat formula is:

```
x + Defence + 2
```

Where `x` is your highest combat level (excluding prayer and Constitution).

For example, a player has 50 defence, 50 attack, 50 strength, 60 ranged, 60 magic, 99 prayer, 40 summoning and 99 constitution. The player's combat level will be:

```
60 + 50 + 2
```

Which equals `112`.

In your example, you had all 1 combat skills (except 10 constitution). So now, you would have:

```
1 (highest cb skill) + 1 (defence) + 2
```

Which equals `4`.

Comment: Hey Terry, just letting ya know this answer is outdated.

Comment: @WeckarE Yea, the whole question is lol